# State of Variable Changes During Recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to understand the difference between when we `return` a value as compared to call a function during recursion. `Return` concept makes sense to me, hence I am only presenting my code while calling a function and the output.

```
d={2:'ab'}

def print_str(digit,curr_idx,output):
  if curr_idx==len(d[digit]):
    #print(output)
    return
  for j in range(curr_idx,len(d[digit])):
    output.append(d[digit][j])
    print_str(digit,curr_idx+1,output)
    print(j,output)


print_str(2,0,[])
```

Here the goal is to print all characters individually, hence `[a,b]`.That is being taken care of in the statement;

```
if curr_idx=2:
   print (output) /*output has been suppressed for brevity*/
   return
```

But my question is regarding the last statement in the `for` loop; `print(j,output)`. It gives the output as;

```
1 ['a', 'b']
0 ['a', 'b']
1 ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
1 ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b']
```

I am not being able to understand the second line of this output; when `j=0` in the previous function call, the output shd be `['a']`, which is the value of `output` when the function was called. But how come we are seeing the output as `0, ['a','b']`. Can I kindly get some help to understand it? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `print_str(digit,curr_idx+1,output)` first.

When it is *called* the value is ['a'], But the result of that function call will `.append` to the list you passed in. The recursive call returns, and then you print the content of the list, which has been changed inside the recursive call.

Stop thinking about *variable changes*. The *variable* didn't change. Variables change when you do something like `my_var = something`. Instead, you *mutated the object that the variable is referring to*. This is no more mysterious than:

```
def bar(data):
    data.append('bar')

def foo(input):
    input.append('foo')
    bar(input)
    print(input)

foo([])
```

This will print `['foo', 'bar']` not `['foo']`, even though when you call `bar` the list being referred to by `input` has the value `['bar']`

Answer (score 0):

You say you understand returns, but it looks like that's not quite the case. A function always returns a value, but if you don't tell it to return something specifically, it will return `None`.

Return values play a very important role in recursion, for example:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n-1)
```

You can use `return` to just stop execution of the current call of a function, but that's far from its main use.

As others have pointed out, changing the contents of a list doesn't change what list it is. So:

```
a = []
a[1] = 'one'
a[2] = 'two'
```

After this, you'd expect `a` to look like `[1, 2]`, and it does. It's no different when you do it in a function, recursive or otherwise:

```
def add_number(xs, n):
    if n > 1:
        add_number(xs, n-1)
    xs.append(n)


my_list = []
add_number(my_list, 3)
```

Run it and `my_list` will be `[1, 2, 3]`, even though it may seem like it only ever gets called with the 'value' of an empty list. The function isn't called with the value of the list, or a copy of the list, but instead a reference to the existing list is passed around and manipulated by the various iterations of the function.

Comment: Agree with your reasoning. Actually return is being used in a way to stop the execution, which is not the ideal use of it.